# Сжать картинку Android

Tags: android, изображения, android-intent

Вот пришло задание:
Нужно выполнить обычный интент для выбора картинки с галереи. 
В обычный `ImageView` в приложении нужно вставить картинку в ужатом виде (thumbnail), а оригинал сохраняем для дальнейшей обработки. Также нужно предусмотреть загрузку больших картинок.

Можете подсказать как организовать UI и как сжать мне картинку и поместить в `ImageView` а оригинал сохранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы запростить картинку из галереи, надо послать системе подобный интент:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите изображение");
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

Система вернет `Uri` выранного файла

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
            // TODO: вот выбранный файл
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Uri` будет вида "context:\....."
Получить из него поток данных можно так:

```
InputStream fileStream = null;
try {
    fileStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
}
```

Как эффективно работать с картинками и загружать их в нужном разрешении, хорошо описано здесь:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

`BitmapFactory` умеет работать не только с ресурсами приложения, но и с файлами и потоками.